# How to display my text label before response.redirect(request.rawurl)

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to display my status_lbl text label before

> Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

I've tried with putting delay time before the redirect page function, but still it doesn't show the status_lbl text label.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script;
using System.Web.Security;

namespace TagNumberWeb
{
public partial class Main : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CrUserID = Request.QueryString["LogInUser"].ToString();
        string Result = Request.QueryString["Result"].ToString();

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CrUserID) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Result))
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login Page.aspx");
            }

            else
            {                    
                UserID.Text = Request.QueryString["LogInUser"].ToString();
                status_lbl.Visible = false;
                GridView1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sONbr = sONbrTextBox.Text;
        string SOLine = sOLineTextBox.Text;
        string SerialNbr = serialNbrTextBox.Text;
        string StatusCode = statusCodeComboBox.Text;
        string CrUserID = Request.QueryString["LogInUser"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sONbr) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SOLine) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StatusCode) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(SerialNbr))
        {
            status_lbl.Text = "Please fill in all the information.";
            status_lbl.Visible = true;
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            return;
        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CrUserID))
        {
            status_lbl.Text = "Please login your account!";
            status_lbl.Visible = true;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Please login your account!')</script>");
            Response.Redirect("Login Page.aspx");
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            return;
        }

        else if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr_BCSystem"].ToString());
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.CommandText = "usp_TagNumberUpdate";

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sONbr", sONbr);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOLine", SOLine);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNbr", SerialNbr);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusCode", StatusCode);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrUserID", CrUserID);

            SqlParameter ReturnVal = comm.Parameters.Add("@return", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
            ReturnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string val = (string)ReturnVal.Value;

            conn.Close();
            status_lbl.Text = val;
            status_lbl.Visible = true;
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);

        }

        else 
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr_BCSystem"].ToString());
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.CommandText = "usp_TagNumberUpdateNoSN";

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sONbr", sONbr);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOLine", SOLine);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusCode", StatusCode);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrUserID", CrUserID);

            SqlParameter ReturnVal = comm.Parameters.Add("@return", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
            ReturnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string val = (string)ReturnVal.Value;

            conn.Close();
            status_lbl.Text = val;
            status_lbl.Visible = true;
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because, when you are redirecting to the same page, the context gets lost.

```
Page_Load
```

event gets executed again.

You should change your code like below.

change your `Button1_Click` to :

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string sONbr = sONbrTextBox.Text;
        string SOLine = sOLineTextBox.Text;
        string SerialNbr = serialNbrTextBox.Text;
        string StatusCode = statusCodeComboBox.Text;
        string CrUserID = Request.QueryString["LogInUser"].ToString();

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sONbr) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SOLine) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(StatusCode) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(SerialNbr))
        {
            status_lbl.Text = "Please fill in all the information.";
            status_lbl.Visible = true;
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            return;
        }

        else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CrUserID))
        {
            status_lbl.Text = "Please login your account!";
            status_lbl.Visible = true;
            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "validation", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Please login your account!')</script>");
            Response.Redirect("Login Page.aspx");
            GridView1.Visible = false;
            return;
        }

        else if (CheckBox1.Checked == true)
        {

            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr_BCSystem"].ToString());
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.CommandText = "usp_TagNumberUpdate";

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sONbr", sONbr);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOLine", SOLine);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SerialNbr", SerialNbr);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusCode", StatusCode);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrUserID", CrUserID);

            SqlParameter ReturnVal = comm.Parameters.Add("@return", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
            ReturnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string val = (string)ReturnVal.Value;

            conn.Close();
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl+"?status="+val);

        }

        else 
        {
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr_BCSystem"].ToString());
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand comm = conn.CreateCommand();
            comm.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            comm.CommandText = "usp_TagNumberUpdateNoSN";

            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sONbr", sONbr);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SOLine", SOLine);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StatusCode", StatusCode);
            comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CrUserID", CrUserID);

            SqlParameter ReturnVal = comm.Parameters.Add("@return", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200);
            ReturnVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

            comm.ExecuteNonQuery();

            string val = (string)ReturnVal.Value;

            conn.Close();
            Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl+"?status="+val);
        }
    }
```

and your `Page_Load` should be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string CrUserID = Request.QueryString["LogInUser"].ToString();
        string Result = Request.QueryString["Result"].ToString();
        if(Request.RawUrl.Contains("?status"))
        {
           string val=Request["status"];
           status_lbl.Text = val;   
           status_lbl.Visible = true;
        }
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CrUserID) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Result))
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login Page.aspx");
            }

            else
            {                    
                UserID.Text = Request.QueryString["LogInUser"].ToString();
                status_lbl.Visible = false;
                GridView1.Visible = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I use `Response.Redirect(Request.RawUrl)` to clear up my `textbox` field after i submitted my data, so what i need is to display my status_lbl text label before the redirect page occurs.

Comment: Replace with your code in but still no text label display.

Comment: Yup, replaced my code with yours clean, but still after submitted the data no text label display.